# python argparse - using list option with nargs shows scrambled help message

Tags: python, argparse

I'm using argparse to accept options and one of them is a list:

```
parser.add_argument('-S', '--size', help='Number of results to show', default=1000, dest='size', metavar='')
parser.add_argument('-H','--hostname', nargs='*', help='Hostname list', dest='hostname', metavar='')
```

When I use the nargs option the help message doesn't look so good:

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -S , --size           Number of results to show
  -H [ [ ...]], --hostname [ [ ...]]
                        Hostname list
```

How can I make the hostname look like the rest of the arguments? the metavar='' trick doesn't work here.

Thanks.

Comment: your code has a typo (missing quote)

Comment: do you really need `nargs='*'` ? Are mutiple or zero hostnames allowed?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre - you're right, I've fixed it but the typo is only in the question and not in the code im running.

Comment: @RomanSusi- Yes

Comment: @DianaZvulun I figured that out, but it makes your question less credible.

Comment: if you remove the metavar (or give a name like `HOST`), you will get the correct syntax definition for `-H`. Why do you want to break it? You can override the help if you are not satisfied with the correct way to display invocation syntax.

Comment: @RomanSusi thanks, I was just wondering if there is a way to show the -H option without [ [ ...]] , just like the size option.

Comment: But then it will not tell the whole truth: Namely, it will not say there could be any number of HOSTNAMEs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` formatting is fixed as that nested `[]`.  It's supposed to convey the sense that zero, one or more strings are accepted. Also it affects both the usage and the help line. Metavar allows some control, but not full replacement.

```
In [461]: p=argparse.ArgumentParser()
In [462]: a=p.add_argument('-f','--foo',nargs='*')
In [463]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f [FOO [FOO ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f [FOO [FOO ...]], --foo [FOO [FOO ...]]
```

One string:

```
In [464]: a.metavar = 'F'
In [465]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f [F [F ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f [F [F ...]], --foo [F [F ...]]
```

A tuple:

```
In [467]: a.metavar = ('A','B')
In [468]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h] [-f [A [B ...]]]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f [A [B ...]], --foo [A [B ...]]
```

Complete suupression of the help:

```
In [469]: a.help = argparse.SUPPRESS
In [470]: p.print_help()
usage: ipython3 [-h]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
```

There's always to option of subclassing the help formatter, and changing one or two methods.

The `HelpFormatter` method that uses the metavar:

```
def _format_args(self, action, default_metavar):
    get_metavar = self._metavar_formatter(action, default_metavar)
    if action.nargs is None:
        result = '%s' % get_metavar(1)
    elif action.nargs == OPTIONAL:
        result = '[%s]' % get_metavar(1)
    elif action.nargs == ZERO_OR_MORE:
        result = '[%s [%s ...]]' % get_metavar(2)
    elif action.nargs == ONE_OR_MORE:
        result = '%s [%s ...]' % get_metavar(2)
    elif action.nargs == REMAINDER:
        result = '...'
    elif action.nargs == PARSER:
        result = '%s ...' % get_metavar(1)
    else:
        formats = ['%s' for _ in range(action.nargs)]
        result = ' '.join(formats) % get_metavar(action.nargs)
    return result
```